# PHP Post Variable Problem

Tags: php

It's been a little while with PHP, so please excuse my ignorance. I have this web page:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db ("expiration");

if (isset ($_REQUEST['new_expire']) && $_REQUEST['new_expire'] != "") {
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO files (path, expires) VALUES ('";
    $insert_query .= $_REQUEST['new_path'];
    $insert_query .= "', '";
    $insert_query .= $_REQUEST['new_expire'];
    $insert_query .= "');";
    mysql_query ($insert_query);
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php echo print_r $_REQUEST; ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <p>Add New Expiration</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Select File:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="new_path">
                        <?php $options = buildOptions (); echo $options; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    MySQL Expire Time:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="new_expire" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close ();
?>
```

When I load the page, the result of the `print_r` is an empty array. When I submit the form, it's still empty. I get no new record in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: `print_r()` by default already outputs its results directly, so there's no need to add `echo`, as that'd just spit out the value returned by print_r, which is TRUE. Of course, since PHP's hallmark is (in)consistence, if you do `print_r(true)` it returns that dump and THEN your echo would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change all the places you have `id` to `name`, for example:

`<input type="text" id="new_expire" />` --> `<input type="text" name="new_expire" />`

The `_REQUEST` (either `_POST` or `_GET`) is only from input elements with a `name`

Comment: @Raynos, game it? what does that mean?